# How to execute PDO outside of loop?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

you guys always saying that is it not a good particle to execute SQL queries inside in loops. So how can I run these PDO queries outside of foreach loop?

So first of all I submit a form where I have selected checkboxes.

```
<input type='checkbox'  name='check_list[]' value='" . $row['c.id'] . "'>
```

I want to get these data's and submit to API:
Name, Phone, City, Adress, Country.

I need to put in foreach loop the `$select = $_POST['check_list'];` to SELECT each selected checkbox (customer) data (Name, Phone, City, Adress, Country).

```
foreach ($select as $selected) {

    $stmtgetuserdata = $connpdo->prepare("SELECT c.name, c.phone, 
                                                c.city, c.adress, c.country
                                      FROM `customers` c 
                                      WHERE c.id = :id");
    $stmtgetuserdata->execute([":id"=>$selected]);

    /// FETCH CUSTOMER DATA

    $customerdata  = $stmtgetuserdata->fetch();
    $name          = $customerdata['name'];
    $phone         = $customerdata['phone'];
    $city         = $customerdata['city'];
    $adress        = $customerdata['adress'];
    $country        = $customerdata['country'];

    /// INSERT TO API

    $api = new APIclient(API_EMAIL, API_KEY);

    $api->setClient(array(
            'name' => $name,
            'address' => $adress,
            'city' => $city,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'country_iso_id' => $country
        ));
 
    /// SAVE
    $response = $api->save();

    // IF WAS SUCCESSFUL
    if ($response->error === 0) {
        $stmtupdatesup = $connpdo->prepare("UPDATE customers 
                                     SET status = 'SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED'
                                     WHERE id =:id");
        $stmtupdatesup->execute([":id"=>$selected]);
    } else {
        $stmtupdatesup = $connpdo->prepare("UPDATE customers 
                                            SET status = 'API ERROR' 
                                            WHERE id =:id");
        $stmtupdatesup->execute([":id"=>$selected]);
    }
}
```

In this example how can I put outside of the foreach loop these queries?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

And what if I have one more loop in this foreach loop for example:

```
//// GET PRODUCT DATA
$stmtgetproductdata = $connpdo->prepare("SELECT products.productid, 
                                                    orderitems.item_price, 
                                                    products.productname, 
                                                    products.productqty
                                         FROM `orders` 
                                         INNER JOIN orderitems ON orderitems.orderid = orders.orderid 
                                         INNER JOIN products ON products.productid = orderitems.productid 
                                         WHERE orders.customerid =:id");
            
$stmtgetproductdata->execute([":id"=>$selected]);

while ($rowproduct = $stmtgetproductdata->fetch()) {
    $price       = $rowproduct['item_price'];
    $productqty  = $rowproduct['productqty'];
    $productname = $rowproduct['productname'];
    $productid   = $rowproduct['productid'];

    /// ADD ITEMS TO INVOICE
    $api->addItem(array(
        'name' => $productname,
        'quantity' => $productqty,
        'stock_item_id' => $productid,
        'price' => $price,
        'unit' => 'ks',
        'tax' => 20.00
    ));
} // END WHILE
```

Is it still okay?

Comment: Store `$selected` in an array then do `SET status = 'SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED' WHERE id in()` and update all success ones at once. Same with failure, but different array. (You should prepare outside loop as well).

Comment: you can do it in a loop

Comment: If all your checkboxes have the name `name='check_list'`, then you should not have anything much to "loop over" here in the first place - PHP _overwrites_ multiple values passed under the same parameter name, unless you use "square bracket" syntax in the field names, so this should be `name='check_list[]'` to begin with. (Unless the form does not get submitted directly, but the data is assembled per JavaScript first or something.)

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: And you can trim a lot of fat off that code if you were so inclined

Comment: No idea why people think thay have to move data from a perfectly good array or object into a scaler variable in order to use it in another function call. It a waste of CPU cycles and memory

Comment: My favorite is when there's a long list of `$persons_name = $_POST['persons_name']`. (And favorite-favorite is when followed by `if(isset($persons_name)`.) If you must have scalars, you could `extract()` for example, or even `list` or whatever, instead of hard-coding these assignments one by one. But really just pass the array into your API method. If there are more fields from the query than should pass to API, use `array_intersect_key()`, or just write your query with matching columns, and if need be aliases to match the array keys that your API method is expecting.